# Unable to push into empty Array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

The findOne query is returning a user from the DB. When i console.log(user) it does print out user data. But for some reason isn't pushing into user_contacts. Its just returning as an empty array.

```
get_contacts: function (req, res){
                var user_contacts = [];
                for(var i=0;i<req.body.contacts.length;i++){
                    User.findOne({_id: req.body.contacts[i]._User}, function (err, user) {
                        if(user){
                            console.log(user);
                            user_contacts.push(user);
                        }else{
                            console.log("Error");
                        }
                    })  
                }
            console.log(user_contacts);
            res.json(user_contacts);
            }
```

This should be so simple, but just cannot see what I am doing wrong. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The DB call is async - when you call `res.json` your DB calls haven't executed yet - hence the empty response.

Comment: but the console.log(user) is still printing out the user data, if the DB calls haven't executed how can I have user data to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the call is async - your logs and response are executed before everything is finished. You'll probably also run into some issues with looping that async call - your best bet is to use `$in` and then return:

```
get_contacts: function (req, res){
    var ids = req.body.contacts.map(function(contact) { return contact._User });
    User.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function(err, users) {
        res.json(users)
    });
}
```

Comment: will this not return only one single user data? .. I am trying to retrieve multiple users data together. Thus created the empty array and tried pushing.

Comment: This will query all the `ids` of the users passed back and return an array @Ani777

Comment: tried it, it works. Thanks a lot. 

so basically whats happening is ids is returning all the _User fields in req.body.contacts and the the Query is searching for users with the ids that have been returned. Am i right? 

will be reading about $in as well.

Comment: @Ani777 -- Yep - that's exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0):

User.findOne({}) is [async](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), which mean the callback function *where you push data into user_contacts array* is executed with delay.
Therefore, the moment you console.log, user_contacts is still empty.

Comment: Thanks for the link to async, reading it right now, hope can make some sense out of it.